# reactor.core does not use all the threads in a Scheduler while parallel processing

Tags: java, project-reactor

Why only the number of core threads can be used but not the maximum number of threads?

```
@Test
public void testParallel() throws InterruptedException {
  ThreadPoolExecutor RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL =
      new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 256,
          30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
          new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1024),
          new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Range-Scheduler-%d").build(),
          new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
  RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
  Scheduler RANGE_SCHEDULERS_POOL = Schedulers.fromExecutor(RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL);
  ParallelFlux<String> parallelFlux = Flux.range(1, 500).parallel(20).runOn(RANGE_SCHEDULERS_POOL).flatMap(index -> {
      Mono<String> supplier = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
          Random random = new Random();
          try {
              Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
          return String.format("mono1-%s-%d%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), index);
      });
      return supplier.map(obj -> obj);
  });

  Mono<List<String>> mono1 = parallelFlux.collectSortedList(Comparator.comparingInt(Object::hashCode));
  mono1.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);

  Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
      while (true){
          System.out.println(RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL);
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
      }
  });
  th.start();
  Thread.sleep(60_000_000);
}
```

output

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6fc2ae19[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 17, completed tasks = 20]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6fc2ae19[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 17, completed tasks = 20]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6fc2ae19[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 17, completed tasks = 20]

How to use the maximum number of threads?

Comment: Can you try `Mono.fromSupplier({...}).subscribeOn(RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL)`?

Comment: how should i write

Comment: Just add it anywhere to the supplier. Like it wrote it. Or it could be `supplier.map(obj -> obj).subscribeOn(RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Custom thread pool executor in your code uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue` as a workQueue. Executors in java have some guidelines on how and when a new thread will be spawned in case a new task arrives. This is defined as follows:

When a new task comes

- If number of active threads are < `corePoolSize`, then that task is not queued and a new thread is created for the same.
- If number of active threads are => `corePoolSize`, then the task will be added into the queue.
- If a request cannot be queued and number of active threads >= `corePoolSize`, then a new thread will be created without exceeding the `maxPoolSize`

In your case since you have a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with capacity of 1024, Executor will not spawn a new thread other than the limit of `corePoolSize` until the queue capacity is full.
If you play around with queue capacity to 5 or 10, you will see pool size increasing.

Example modifiying your execuotor to have workqueue capacity of 5

```
ThreadPoolExecutor RANGE_SCHEDULER_POOL =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    3,
                    256,
                    30L,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(5),
                    new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Range-Scheduler-%d").build(),
                    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
            );
```

returns the below output with pool size increasing from 3 to 15

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@69a10787[Running, pool size = 15, active threads = 15, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 20]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@69a10787[Running, pool size = 15, active threads = 15, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 20]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@69a10787[Running, pool size = 15, active threads = 15, queued tasks = 5, completed tasks = 20]
```

You can get more info on these [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512697/7768922)